# Uncaught TypeError: Popper is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, tippyjs

I try to edit CSS stlye of Tippy.js.
So I npm install tippy and import it to my html like this

```
<script src="/min/tippy.js/umd/index.all.js"></script>
```

But, it has some error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Popper is not a constructor
    at createPopperInstance (createTippy.ts:677)
    at mount (createTippy.ts:694)
    at Object.show (createTippy.ts:961)
    at new_control.js:128
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at createGraph (new_control.js:101)
    at Object.success (new_control.js:6)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

So, I have tried to npm install popper in my directory working file but,it's not work at all. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nice try although i would reccomend after installing popper by npm install, try to add this to your HTML file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: then why even use npm? you are including popper twice

Comment: No need to do npm install, it will work with the above CDN.

Comment: I got this error with popper 2, using popper 1 does the trick